# Get data from nfo file with functions Python

Tags: python

I am learning python and I have made a function to get text from a .nfo file, improving on this block of code:

```
        # Book Author
        _author = ["Author:", "Author.."]

        logger_nfo.info('Searching Author book...')
        with open(nfofile, "r+", encoding='utf-8') as file1:
            fileline1 = file1.readlines()
            for x in _author:  # <--- Loop through the list to check
                for line in fileline1:  # <--- Loop through each line
                    line = line.casefold()  # <--- Set line to lowercase
                    if x.casefold() in line:
                        logger_nfo.info('Line found with word: %s', x)
                        nfo_author = line

        if nfo_author == '':
            logger_nfo.warning('Author not found.')
```

I've made this function:

```
nfofile_link = "The Sentence.nfo"
search_for = ["Author:", "Author.."]


def search_nfo(nfofile_link, search_for):
    logger_nfo.info('Searching nfo')
    with open(nfofile_link, "r+", encoding='utf-8') as file1:
        fileline1 = file1.readlines()
        for x in search_for:  # <--- Loop through the list to check
            for line in fileline1:  # <--- Loop through each line
                line = line.casefold()  # <--- Set line to lowercase
                if x.casefold() in line:
                    logger_nfo.info('Line found with word: %s', x)
                    global nfo_author
                    nfo_author = line


search_nfo(nfofile_link, search_for)
print(nfo_author)
```

This works, but I'd like to improve it, how can I do that?

An example of the .nfo file's content:

```
General Information
===================
 Title:                  Agent in Berlin
 Author:                 Alex Gerlis
 Read By:                Duncan Galloway
 Copyright:              2021
 Audiobook Copyright:    2021
 Genre:                  Audiobook
 Publisher:              Canelo
 Series Name:            Wolf Pack Spies 
 Position in Series:     01
 Abridged:               No

Original Media Information
==========================
 Media:                  Downloaded
 Source:                 Audible
 Condition:              New

File Information
================
 Number of MP3s:         42
 Total Duration:         11:33:05
 Total MP3 Size:         319.23 MB
 Encoded At:             64 kbit/s 22050 Hz Mono
 ID3 Tags:               Set, v1.1, v2.3
```

Comment: Please show sample nfo content.

Comment: i update the question

Comment: What kind of improvements are you looking for?

Comment: First the encoding, i think the nfo. file is not always ut8(can i use others encodings?). Is it proper to use global variable? in a way maybe something to improve.

Comment: @Teepeemm done thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Embrace functions, not global variables**. It's good that you put your code
in a function. However, you are not taking full advantage of the power of
functions because you use the function to modify a global variable. Except
under very rare circumstances, that is not a good idea. Instead, functions
should take arguments and returns values. Organize your programs around that
basic model.

**Push algorithmic details into easily testable functions**. A function that
requires a file to exist is more awkward to test and debug than a function that
takes text and returns a value. A simple data-oriented function, for example,
can be pasted into a Python REPL and experimented with. An automated test for
such a function is easy to write because you only need to define a list/tuple
of strings and pass them into the function. For such reasons, I would reduce
`search_nfo()` to the bare minimum: open the file, read the lines, and do any
needed logging. That's it. Delegate most of the work -- in particular, the
algorithmic details that might contain bugs, that might require debugging,
testing, or future modification -- to a separate function.

**Don't lowercase more often than you need to**. Currently you are lowercasing
values inside of nested for-loops. That's not a huge problem if the volume of
data is moderate or small. Nonetheless, it's a decent idea to practice good
habits of editing your code to weed out unnecessary operations. Don't take that
virtue to unreasonable extremes, but keep it in mind.

```
def main():
    nfo_author = search_nfo('foobar.nfo', ('Author:', 'Author..'))
    print(nfo_author)

def search_nfo(nfofile_link, search_for):
    with open(nfofile_link) as fh:
        nfo_author = search_nfo_lines(fh.readlines(), search_for)
        return nfo_author

def search_nfo_lines(lines, search_for):
    targets = tuple(s.casefold() for s in search_for)
    for line in lines:
        lower_line = line.casefold()
        if any(t in lower_line for t in targets):
            # Do you want to return the original line
            # or the lowercase line? Adjust as needed.
            return line
    return None

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: To complete this question I would add what @n3buchadnezzar did: instead of loadig a whole file into memory `file.readlines()`, processing it line by line using a `Generator` by `yield`ing. It also separates the concerns of file reading and content processing.

Comment: @MiguelAlorda Your point is often a good one, but it depends on the larger context. If the typical data file is like the example we were given (small to moderate in size), I would not bother with that unless some other aspect of the code base pushed me in that direction. Separation of concerns has already been accomplished by detaching opening/reading from parsing, as done here. Whether to switch from slurping-whole-file vs line-based-yielding is a different matter.

Comment: While @N3buchadnezzar solution is great for same type of .nfo, i feel this solution will be better for my problem.

Answer (score 4):

I agree wholeheartedly with the other answers here, and I will just chip in my two cents.

**Conversion of data structures** You are reading in a `nfo` file, it would be wise to convert this into an object Python is more familiar with. If you are doing more with the file a `NFO` class is probably the best, but for now I feel the content of the file can best be expressed through a dictionary.

**Returning from functions** As mentioned previously we want to make full use of our functions and avoid global variables by returning or `yielding`. If we want the contents of the nfo file line by line we can do the following

```
from pathlib import Path
from pprint import pprint
from typing import Iterable


def path_2_nfo(path: Path) -> Iterable[str]:
    with open(path, "r+") as f:
        for line in f:
            if stripped := line.strip():
                yield stripped
```

The code above will return the contents of the nfo file line by line. You can for instance try to run the code below to see what it does

```
BOOK_PATH = Path(r"The Sentence.nfo")
nfo = path_2_nfo(BOOK_PATH)
for line in nfo:
    print(line)
```

I will also *strongly* recommend avoiding special characters in file names, but that is a story for another day. The second part is simply reading our `nfo` into a dict. From a first glance your nfo consists of three different objects: **The header** single line, contains no `:`, **linebreak** a full line of `=`, and lastly the **content** a line containing `:`.

Reading the file line by line and filtering based on these three types can look like

```
def nfo_2_dict(nfo: Iterable[str], sep: str = ":") -> dict:
    nfo_dict = dict()
    for line in nfo:

        is_linebreak = all("=" == char for char in line)
        is_content = sep in line
        is_header = not is_linebreak and not is_content

        if is_header:
            header = line
            nfo_dict[header] = dict()
        elif is_content:
            value, *content = line.split(sep)
            nfo_dict[header][value] = sep.join(c.strip() for c in content)


    return nfo_dict
```

Where our main now simply becomes

```
BOOK_PATH = Path(r"The Sentence.nfo")
nfo = path_2_nfo(BOOK_PATH)
nfo_dict = nfo_2_dict(nfo)

print(nfo_dict["General Information"]["Author"])
pprint(nfo_dict)
```

Depending on how often you need to search the file, I feel it is much cleaner to simply create a dictionary than searching the file each time.

Comment: If you used `for line in f:` instead of `for line in f.readlines():` it would not load the whole file into memory before yielding it line by line. The thing returned by `open` is also a generator. And instead of `Union[Iterator[str], list[str]]` you could just use the easier to read and more generic `Iterable[str]`.

Comment: @Graipher great comments. i've updated my answer accordingly! I tried with just `Iterator[str]` and it complained when I added a list, but `Iterable ` does the trick. Thanks